# Using jQuery toggle to show content, but prevent closing when the user clicks on an input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is a drop-down list, implemented approximately like this:

```
    <ul>
<li>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <p>block 1</p>
   <span>
    <b>Here is some text</b>
    <input type="text" placeholder="ENTER HERE">
   </span>
</li>
<li> 
   <div class="block"></div>
   <p>block 2</p>
    <span>
     <b>Here is some text</b>
     <input type="text" placeholder="ENTER HERE">
    </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

In the list there are some text, and input.

JS :

```
$(function(){
  $('ul li').click(function(){
  $('span', this).toggle();
});
});
```

Now the problem is, if you click on the input field, then the list will be closed immediately, how to avoid it?

Also, using css I added a triangle which when clicked should be rotated 180 degrees, what is the best way to implement this?

Here, example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8c7effx/1/)

Thank you google translater =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z8c7effx/14/

I added

```
$('input[type=text]').click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();    
});
```

to prevent event propagation, to prevent closing of li.

Also added rotation of the arrow using following css class.

```
.selected
{
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: 20px 8px;
}
```

Comment: This will work fine, though, if the user clicks on any other child of the `li` the `li` will still be toggled.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
    <input type="text" onclick="Focus()"/>

<script>
        function Focus(){
        var dropDownList = document.getElementById("yourDropdownId")style.display="block";

        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

About problem with drop-down - update javascript to this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.block').click(function(){
        var target = $(this).parent();
    $('span', target).toggle();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you could check the event target, and let the span toggling only when user click the caret

[modified example](https://jsfiddle.net/1qjqntz3/)

```
$(function(){
    $('ul li').click(function(e){
         if($(e.target).hasClass('block')){
             $('span', this).toggle();
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the generic nature of your click selector. Clicking on an `input` element allows the click event to bubble up to the original `li` element, thus toggling the `li`. You can check to see if the target matches the `li` element or not, and then toggle accordingly:

```
$('ul li').click(function(e){
    if (e.target == this)
        $('span', this).toggle();
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hwsefq7c/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function i made it

```
 $(function(){
var container=$("input");
 $('ul li').click(function(e){
 if(!container.is(e.target))
 $('span', this).toggle();
 })
 })
```

this will check whether the cick target is input or not . and toggle it on the basis of this

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the toggle() function on all li elements. Even if you click on the input element this will be triggered. There is something called event bubbling and event capturing -> just google it :D

You can stop this event mechanics on many ways. I think this could be the easiest way:

```
$('input').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Mahesh Chavda was faster :(

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
$('ul li').click(function(){
   $('span', this).toggle();
   if($("#input1").is(":focus")){
      $("#span1").show();
    }
    if($("#input2").is(":focus")){
      $("#span2").show();
    }
else{
//no focus for input and textarea
} 
});
});
```

```css
 .block {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
   }
   .block::after {
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute;
    border: 15px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 20px solid red;
   }
   ul span{
     display:none;
   }
   ul li{
     padding:10px;
     border: 1px solid grey;
     list-style: none;
   
   }
   ul{
     margin: 0;
     padding:0;
   }
   ul p{
     display: inline-block;
     padding-left: 50px;
     margin: 0;
   }
   b{
     padding:30px;
     display:block;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
<div class="block"></div>
<p>Блок 1</p>
<span id="span1">
<b>Тут много текста</b>
<input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="ENTER HERE">
</span>
</li>
<li> 
<div class="block"></div>
<p>Блок 2</p>
<span id="span2">
<b>Тут много текста</b>
<input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="ENTER HERE">
</span>
</li>
</ul>
```